# Crop specific area in caffe layer

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am building an image classification in caffe. All images are fixed size and I know their nature. Now I want to guide Neural Network to look closer to the specific area, as I know that this area carries a lot of information. And in the end, I want to combine to layer stacks back. This is what I achieved with a custom python layer which crops a specific area for me.

[image]

The thing is Python layer even doing its job is very slow. I know about caffe crop layer, but it looks like it doesn't do what I want, as far as I understood it only aligns 1 shape to another, However, I can't specify are direct.

Am I missing something here? It looks like it should be simpler solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Crop layer with DummyData layer as a second bottom layer